# How to split a string into characters in python

Tags: python, string

I have a string 'ABCDEFG'
I want to be able to list each character sequentially followed by the next one.
Example

A B

B C

C D

D E

E F

F G

G

Can you tell me an efficient way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: I tried saving it as a list but I am unable to iterate the list

Comment: Show us the code, so one of us can help you with exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: I saved the above string in a file ref.txt and the ran this piece of code which lists the whole string but not the characters iterativelyif __name__ == '__main__':
        with open('ref.txt') as f:
                f1 = f.read().splitlines()
                l = list(f1)
                print l, f1, len(l)

Comment: To split a string into a list of characters, all you need is `list(s)`. But you generally don't even need that—the string itself is already an iterable of characters, just like the list, so almost anywhere you could do something like `for ch in list(s):` you could just as easily have done `for ch in s:`.

Comment: @Ssank: Don't try to describe your code in comments, edit your question to include the code. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help for more.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, looks like this could be closed, but you have some answers, and we don't *require* code to accept questions, so maybe this will stay open. Regardless, you'd probably have fewer downvotes if you had included some code you had already attempted. Remember, if you accept an answer, you'll get plus 2 to your rep, though. Good luck, and +1 for a small diversion!

Answer (score 3):

In Python, a string is already seen as an enumerable list of characters, so you don't need to split it; it's already "split".  You just need to build your list of substrings.

It's not clear what form you want the result in.  If you just want substrings, this works:

```
s = 'ABCDEFG'
[s[i:i+2] for i in range(len(s))]
#=> ['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DE', 'EF', 'FG', 'G']
```

If you want the pairs to themselves be lists instead of strings, just call `list` on each one:

```
[list([s[i:i+2]) for i in range(len(s))]
#=> [['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C'], ['C', 'D'], ['D', 'E'], ['E', 'F'], ['F', 'G'], ['G']]
```

And if you want strings after all, but with something like a space between the letters, join them back together after the `list` call:

```
[' '.join(list(s[i:i+2])) for i in range(len(s))]
#=> ['A B', 'B C', 'C D', 'D E', 'E F', 'F G', 'G']
```

Comment: he wants space between characters !

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep the last character, so use `izip_longest` from `itertools`

```
>>> import itertools
>>> s =  'ABCDEFG'
>>> for c, cnext in itertools.izip_longest(s, s[1:], fillvalue=''):
...     print c, cnext
...     
A B
B C
C D
D E
E F
F G
G
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def doit(input):
    for i in xrange(len(input)):
        print input[i] + (input[i + 1] if i != len(input) - 1 else '')

doit("ABCDEFG")
```

Which yields:

```
>>> doit("ABCDEFG")
AB
BC
CD
DE
EF
FG
G
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want space between the characters you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function and list comprehension :

```
>>> s="ABCDEFG"
>>> l=[' '.join(i) for i in zip(s,s[1:])]
['A B', 'B C', 'C D', 'D E', 'E F', 'F G']
>>> for i in l:
...  print i
... 
A B
B C
C D
D E
E F
F G
```

if you dont want space just use list comprehension :

```
    >>> [s[i:i+2] for i in range(len(s))]
['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DE', 'EF', 'FG', 'G']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have a list of strings, not a string:

```
with open('ref.txt') as f:
    f1 = f.read().splitlines()
```

`f.read()` returns a string. You call `splitlines()` on it, getting a list of strings (one per line). If your input is actually `'ABCDEFG'`, this will of course be a list of one string, `['ABCDEFG']`.

```
    l = list(f1)
```

Since `f1` is already a list, this just makes `l` a duplicate copy of that list.

```
     print l, f1, len(l)
```

And this just prints the list of lines, and the copy of the list of lines, and the number of lines.

So, first, what happens if you drop the `splitlines()`? Then `f1` will be the string `'ABCDEFG'`, instead of a list with that one string. That's a good start. And you can drop the `l` part entirely, because `f1` is already an iterable of its characters; `list(f1)` will just be a different iterable of the same characters.

So, now you want to print each letter with the next letter. One way to do that is by `zip`ping `'ABCDEFG'` and `'BCDEFG '`. But how do you get that `'BCDEFG '`? Simple; it's just `f1[1:] + ' '`.

So:

```
with open('ref.txt') as f:
    f1 = f.read()
    for left, right in zip(f1, f1[1:] + ' '):
        print left, right
```

Of course for something this simple, there are many other ways to do the same thing. You can iterate over `range(len(f1))` and get 2-element slices, or you can use `itertools.zip_longest`, or you can write a general-purpose "overlapping adjacent groups of size N from any iterable" function out of `itertools.tee` and `zip`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [itertools pairwise recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) for exactly this use case:

```
import itertools

def pairwise(myStr):
    a,b = itertools.tee(myStr)
    next(b,None)
    for s1,s2 in zip(a,b):
        print(s1,s2)
```

Output:

```
In [121]: pairwise('ABCDEFG')
A B
B C
C D
D E
E F
F G
```